# Marshalling an object to XML is causing duplicate nodes to be added

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling

I have an object that I need to marshal to XML. To do this I am using JAXB. The resulting XML file is created, however I end up with duplicate nodes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<order>
    <supplier_id>suppliername</supplier_id>
    <store_name>storename</store_name>
    <order_id>1234567890</order_id>
    <order_item>
        <order_item_id>0987654321</order_item_id>
        <item_state>Shipped</item_state>
        <item_state_date>2012-12-27T14:40:00.000-05:00</item_state_date>
        <carrier_code>NA</carrier_code>
        <carrier_name>CarrierName</carrier_name>
        <shipping_method>Expedited</shipping_method>
        <tracking_number>348134987124872734817324</tracking_number>
        <backorder_replacement_sku_price>0.0</backorder_replacement_sku_price>
    </order_item>
    <order_item>
        <order_item_id>0987654321</order_item_id>
        <item_state>Shipped</item_state>
        <item_state_date>2012-12-27T14:40:00.000-05:00</item_state_date>
        <carrier_code>NA</carrier_code>
        <carrier_name>CarrierName</carrier_name>
        <shipping_method>Expedited</shipping_method>
        <tracking_number>348134987124872734817324</tracking_number>
        <backorder_replacement_sku_price>0.0</backorder_replacement_sku_price>
    </order_item>
    ....
```

I only require the first `<order_item>` node, and subsequent ones are there erroneously.

My code is as follows:

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(classname.class.getPackage().getName());
Marshaller marsheller = context.createMarshaller();

Order order = new Order();
OrderItem orderItem = new OrderItem();

...Business logic related to our ERP system...
//We start a loop here to iterate over search results. The goal is to have one XML file per search row returned. No knowledge of the ERP system is required. 

for (SearchRow row : results.getSearchRowList().getSearchRow()) {   
    //we capture our variables from the search results here and build our order and orderItem objects with them. 

    order.setSupplierId("suppliername");
    order.setStoreName("storename");
    order.setOrderId(orderNumber);
    orderItem.setOrderItemId(orderItemId);
    orderItem.setItemState(StatusCodeType.SHIPPED);
    orderItem.setItemStateDate(date2);
    orderItem.setCarrierCode("NA");
    orderItem.setCarrierName(carrierName);
    orderItem.setShippingMethod(shippingMethod);
    orderItem.setTrackingNumber(trackingNumber);

    order.getOrderItem().add(orderItem);
    File f = new File("tempFiles/" + order.getOrderId() + ".xml");
    marsheller.marshal(order, f);
}
```

I thought that the issue was the loop, but if I log all the variables *after* object creation from the objects themselves only show orderItem result and not multiple orderItems.

Can anyone point me in the direction where I am going off the tracks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either need to

- create a `new Order()` and `new OrderItem()` each iteration round the loop or
- move the `order.getOrderItem().add(orderItem);` to outside the loop immediately after you create the `Order` and `OrderItem` instances.

Your current logic is adding the same `OrderItem` instance to the list each time round the loop, so the first iteration you'll get one `<order_item>` element, the second iteration you'll get two identical ones, the third iteration three, etc.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Roberts! Blatantly obvious as soon as you pointed it out. I appreciate the quick response :-)